# Image pan and zoom with GWT

Tags: java, gwt, image

I have a fixed size image and I want to show a subset of the image. I want to allow the user to click and drag to move the visible area of the image.

The Image class has a nice setUrlAndVisibleRect method which can handle the image area display. The problem I am having is getting the mouse click and drag to work.

I registered Mouse Down/Up/Move handlers and it all looked very promising in Firefox. Then I tested it in IE8...

The behaviour I see in IE8 as I click and drag:
- MouseDown event when I click
- browser then displays a "no entry" symbol cursor as I drag
- finally when I release I get no mouse up event.

What is the correct way to handle this in a cross browser fashion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use `MouseDownEvent.preventDefault()`. This prevents the browser from taking the default action for the event, which is to initiate the drag action that you see.

If that doesn't work try `MouseMoveEvent.preventDefault()`. One of them will kill it.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up basing my solution on this article:
http://chaoticjava.com/posts/drag-and-drop-in-gwt-the-how-to/

The updated example in the comments uses DOM.eventPreventDefault(event).